# solr real time indexing not working

Tags: indexing, solr, real-time, solrcloud

I recently upgrade the solr from 5.5 to 6.6 and all the index are copied to the new version and all the config are fine.but when I add the softcommit option to sorlconfig.xml the real-time indexing is not working

```
<commitWithin>
    <softCommit>true</softCommit>
    </commitWithin>

    <autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>1000</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>

<commit waitSearcher="false"/> <commit waitSearcher="false"
expungeDeletes="true"/> <optimize waitSearcher="false"/>
```

please help on this is my configuration is wrong.?
 and do I need to add anything additionally?

Comment: Exactly what are the XML you've posted? Are these your commits, your configuration or what?

Comment: this are the configuration in my solrconfig.xml. but right now when i enter a product on my website (input) its not searching once i complete the submit the product. everytime i need to execute the dataimport in solr gui.

Comment: So how are you indexing new documents into Solr? The commit-XML doesn't do anything in `solrconfig.xml`; you're supposed to send that to the Solr server after adding your documents as JSON/XML/etc., and then send the soft commit/hard commit.